# Jenkins not starting or coming back online - HANGING and showing SEVERE: Unable to parse provided JSON - [/var/lib/jenkins/cb-envelope/envelope.json]

Tags: json, parsing, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, restart

**Jenkins**: 2.89.4-x rolling version

Jenkins was running slow due to memory issues.

Restarted Jenkins (sudo/usual way), I got the following SEVERE issue.
Finally Restarted Jenkins machine thinking that'll help; got memory back (mem looks good now).

Trying to start Jenkins again and getting the same SEVERE issue and installation just HANGS at a given plugin while doing `Initializing plugin <somePlugin-here> by pool-6-thread-2`.

```
Running from: /usr/lib/jenkins/jenkins.war
Jun 06, 2019 6:49:14 AM Main deleteWinstoneTempContents
WARNING: Failed to delete the temporary Winstone file /tmp/winstone/jenkins.war
Jun 06, 2019 6:49:14 AM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log initialized
..
...more lines here...
...
..
Jun 06, 2019 6:49:19 AM jenkins.model.Jenkins$5 runTask
INFO: Took 54ms for LogRecorderManager.init by pool-6-thread-7
Jun 06, 2019 6:49:19 AM com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.updates.envelope.LoggerLog log
SEVERE: Unable to parse provided JSON
net.sf.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 0 of 
    at net.sf.json.util.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:499)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject._fromJSONTokener(JSONObject.java:919)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject._fromString(JSONObject.java:1145)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.fromObject(JSONObject.java:162)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.fromObject(JSONObject.java:132)
    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.updates.envelope.JSONObjectLoader.from(JSONObjectLoader.java:38)
    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.updates.envelope.JSONObjectLoader$1.apply(JSONObjectLoader.java:51)
    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.updates.envelope.JSONObjectLoader$1.apply(JSONObjectLoader.java:47)
    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.updates.envelope.Validation$Value.flatMap(Validation.java:229)
    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.updates.envelope.JSONObjectLoader.from(JSONObjectLoader.java:47)
    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.updates.envelope.ParsedEnvelope$Loader.fromJSON(ParsedEnvelope.java:95)
    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.cjp.installmanager.BaseFolder.loadInstalled(BaseFolder.java:136)
    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.cjp.installmanager.WAREnvelope.loadInstalled(WAREnvelope.java:140)
    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.cjp.installmanager.CJPPluginManager$StartUp.execute(CJPPluginManager.java:297)
    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.cjp.installmanager.CJPPluginManager.loadPlugins(CJPPluginManager.java:231)
    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.cjp.installmanager.CJPPluginManager.loadBundledPlugins(CJPPluginManager.java:209)
    at hudson.PluginManager$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:379)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:282)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1066)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:210)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Jun 06, 2019 6:49:19 AM com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.updates.envelope.LoggerLog log
SEVERE: Unable to read JSON from [/var/lib/jenkins/cb-envelope/envelope.json]
Jun 06, 2019 6:49:19 AM jenkins.model.Jenkins$5 runTask
..
..
..
..
..
...more lines here...regarding inspecting/installing/loading/extracting plugins .hpi/.jpi files (looks good no ERROR/FATAL/SEVERE lines in this area).
...
..
..
..
..
..
Jun 06, 2019 6:49:34 AM jenkins.model.Jenkins$5 runTask
INFO: Took 0ms for Initializing plugin ColumnPack-plugin by pool-6-thread-2
Jun 06, 2019 6:49:34 AM jenkins.model.Jenkins$5 runTask
INFO: Took 274ms for Discovering plugin initialization tasks by pool-6-thread-10
Jun 06, 2019 6:49:34 AM jenkins.model.Jenkins$5 runTask
INFO: Took 0ms for SupportPlugin.threadDumpStartup by pool-6-thread-15
Jun 06, 2019 6:49:34 AM jenkins.model.Jenkins$5 runTask
INFO: Took 2ms for XStreamDOMCompat.addAliases by pool-6-thread-16
```

The above log shows only has 1 SEVERE error about the following:

**SEVERE: Unable to parse provided JSON - [/var/lib/jenkins/cb-envelope/envelope.json]**

**Questions:**
1. What is this ***cb-envelop*** folder in JENKINS_HOME?
2. Why Jenkins is not coming up?

I see this folder has `0 byte envelop.json` file and **both** cje-xx folders contain nothing, example `ls` output shown below.

```
[giga123@jenkins_dev_machine ~]$ ls -l /var/lib/jenkins/cb-envelope/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 jenkins_svc_user jenkins_group 4096 Jul  3  2017 cje-2.46.3.2
drwxr-xr-x 2 jenkins_svc_user jenkins_group 4096 Apr 20  2018 cje-2.89.4.2
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins_svc_user jenkins_group    0 Mar 27  2018 envelope.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins_svc_user jenkins_group    0 Jul  5  2017 envelope.json.disabled
[giga123@jenkins_dev_machine ~]$ ls -l /var/lib/jenkins/cb-envelope/cje-2.89.4.2/
total 0
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

Soft fix: Renamed the `envelop.json` file to `envelop.json.disabled`.
*Try Jenkins start* now (**ex:** `sudo /sbin/service jenkins stop/start` and after *start* Jenkins should come up fine. Didn't catch that this issue came sometime back and someone did disable this file for Jenkins to startup.

**The issue** was a BLANK json file (thus '{' parse SEVERE error was coming up).

Hard fix: Rename `/var/lib/jenkins/cb-envelope/` to **/var/lib/jenkins/cb-envelope.OLD**
*Try Jenkins start* now (**ex:** `sudo /sbin/service jenkins stop/start` and after *start* Jenkins should come up fine. `cb-envelop` folder will be recreated (if renamed/deleted) after Jenkins start.

Once this was done `net.sf.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 0 of` error went away and Jenkins installation went a little further **BUT** installation **halted** at a given plugin. I disabled that plugin (by going to `$JENKINS_HOME/plugins/<plugin.jpi_or_hpi>.disabled` and retried to start Jenkins, now it halted at another next plugin in the list of plugins during `Initializing plugin .... plugin...` steps/sub-steps.

**To resolve that**, we had to contact Cloudbees support team and **disable** `support-core.jpi` plugin. This plugin comes with Cloudbees Jenkins Operation Center / Master installation by default as one of the .jpi files.

After `support-core.jpi` file in plugins folder was renamed to `support-core.jpi.disabled` (you can move support-core folder to `support-core.OLD` if you want), we retried starting Jenkins and it came back up fine.

One last thing we noticed was, after Jenkins dashboard was finally UP, it was in `QUITE and SHUTDOWN mode` (by design). To remove state that, we had to click on:

As an admin level user account, Go to `Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > Quiet Restart` and `UN-CHECK` the check box which says **Stay in "queiting down" state when restarted**.

Remove the check from the following.
[image]

On Jenkins dashboard, click `cancel` on `Shut down mode link` (if any) and now Jenkins is up and running fine.